# Using module.exports on arrow functions with (req,res) as parameters

Tags: node.js

I am currently working on a project with node where I need to use module.exports for my functions exports. I export the showMessage function like this:

```
   const  showMessage = (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send(`Message: ${req.param.message}`);
    }

module.exports = {
    showMessage
}
```

And import it here:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const  { showMessage } =  require('../controllers/auth');

router.get("/:message", showMessage);

module.exports = router;
```

And further here:

```
fs.readdirSync("./routes").map((r) => app.use("/api", require(`./routes/${r}`)));
```

My project is supposed to take message from the api and show it on the webpage.
E.g.: If I go to http://localhost:8000/api/good-morning, I should get on my webpage: Message: good-morning
Instead I get Message: undefined. This makes me think that there is a problem with the scope of (req,res) parameteres passed in the showMessage function.

I tried using import <> from <> syntax, but didn't work

Comment: Looking at the source, it seems okay.

Comment: [`req.param`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.param) is a _method_, did you mean [`req.params`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `req.params` instead of `req.param`. Here are the API docs: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params